# sbt run/debug configuration broken showing unknown after upgrading intellij to 2020.1

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-15

I just upgraded IntelliJ community edition to latest version 2020.1 as of today. All my **SBT** run/debug configurations are broken and currently show **Unknown** under Edit configuration.

I have checked the workspace.xml and configuration seems correct.

I have also checked I've got the latest SBT plugin.

Any help or pointers will be much appreciated as I have dozens of projects with lots of configurations so will be annoying to have to create them again.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours finally figure out how to fix the configuration and made them re-appear. I had to change the **workspace.xml** under the .idea folder. Look for your run configuration under the:

```
<component name="RunManager">
```

Seems the previous Intellij version used: **factoryName="sbt Task"**. Note the lower case **sbt**.

New version uses upper case: **factoryName="SBT Task"**

After changing this on all my configurations it worked again.

Comment: Yup, this fixed it for me.

Comment: Can you provide any insight into the way to set this up for new projects without any old configurations?  See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442430/intellij-2020-1-sbt-mainrunner-configuration

Comment: @MichaelWest, you just need to make sure you have installed the sbt/scala plugin in intellij, then simply go the edit configurations and click the + button and you should see the SBT task