# intellij 2020.1 sbt mainRunner configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to follow the [intructions](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/wiki/%5BSBT%5D-How-to-use-provided-libraries-in-run-configurations) for setting up intellij scala project to work with sbt. However, I am not finding the run/configuration described in intellij 2020.1.  Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61246546/sbt-run-debug-configuration-broken-showing-unknown-after-upgrading-intellij-to-2) I understand that the way this is configured has changed.  However, that post describes how to make old project work.  What do I do for new projects?

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Create nice sbt project with idea.sbt already configured with mainRunner

`sbt new tillrohrmann/flink-project.g8`

this includes idea.sbt

```
lazy val mainRunner = project.in(file("mainRunner")).dependsOn(RootProject(file("."))).settings(
  // we set all provided dependencies to none, so that they are included in the classpath of mainRunner
  libraryDependencies := (libraryDependencies in RootProject(file("."))).value.map{
    module => module.configurations match {
      case Some("provided") => module.withConfigurations(None)
      case _ => module
    }
  }
)
```

It also comes with a README.md that says:

```
You can also run your application from within IntelliJ:  select the classpath of the 'mainRunner' module in the run/debug configurations.
Simply open 'Run -> Edit configurations...' and then select 'mainRunner' from the "Use classpath of module" dropbox.
```

2. Import project into intellij 2020.1
3. Now what?  I cannot find a "Use classpath of module" dropbox in intellij 2020.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ's `Use classpath of module` corresponds to the classpath of sbt's sub-project. To create a `Run Configuration` using the classpath of `mainRunner` project try

1. `Run | Edit Configurations...`
2. Click the plus button `+` to  `Add New Configuration`
3. Select `Application`
4. Give it a name say `WordCount`
5. Under `Main Class` specify Scala class with `main` method, say, `org.example.WordCount`
6. `Working directory` should be the root of the project
7. Set `Use classpath of module` to `mainRunner`
8. JRE should be 1.8 or above

[image]

Note as an alternative to using `mainRunner` project you could also use root project but select the checkbox `Include dependencies with "Provided" scope`.

Comment: I've used the Include dpendencies with "Provided" scope option before for this.  I am trying to learn more about sbt.  Using the "Provided" scope seems simplest. Is there any reason to prefer using mainRunner?